# Entropy of independent draws of balls from a bin

Tags: probability, references, conditional-probability, combinatorics

**Problem Setting**

Consider a bin containing $B$ balls, each ball is *red* or *blue* with equal probability ($0.5$). Let $R$ denote the number of *red* balls. It is easy to see that $R \sim Binomial(B,0.5)$

In each round, a ball is drawn **with replacement**. The color of the  ball drawn in the $i^{th}$ round is denoted by random variable $X_i$.

**Question**

What is the conditional entropy of $Y_k = R\big|X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_k$?

$$
H(Y_k) = H\big(R\big|X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_k\big)
$$

In words, $Y_k$ is a random variable denoting the number of *red* balls after seeing the color of balls drawn after $k$ independent draws.

Comment: Write down the probability of observing $X_i$ given $R$ and use Bayes' rule.

Comment: @Neil: It is a good idea. But the expression obtained after Baye's rule is very messy.